# tar command Option Not able to understand

Tags: stdout, tar

1. Check the Size of the tar, tar.gz and tar.bz2 Archive File.

To check the size of any tar, tar.gz and tar.bz2 archive file, use the following command. For example the below command will display the size of archive file in Kilobytes (KB).

```
 tar -czf - tecmint-14-09-12.tar | wc -c
```

12820480

```
 tar -czf - MyImages-14-09-12.tar.gz | wc -c
```

112640

```
 tar -czf - Phpfiles-org.tar.bz2 | wc -c
```

20480

What does  " - " do in this Command not able to find anything related to it in Official tar Documentation : [ref 18](https://www.tecmint.com/18-tar-command-examples-in-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

`-` is the option value for the `-f` option, which is the filename of the output file, normally a tgz filename.

`-` is special in that many tools accept it as an alias for `stdout`, which is in this case a pipe to `wc -c`. Remove the `wc` and you'll see it "messes up" your terminal

---

PS: it seems not documented in the `tar` man page, imo it should.

Comment: can you share any Official Link for better understanding?

Comment: @cmgwins Unfortunately no :) (at least I couldn't find something yet, man tar doesn't mention it at least)